# Highlighting a DataGrid row in Flex based on an IF Statement

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

I have a series of DataGrids which will pull data in from a query regularly. I want to highlight an entire row if a specified value in one column of that row is above a certain threshold. So I need to be able to parse through every row in a DataGrid and highlight any row that has a specific value above "100" say. The amount of data in the DataGrids is going to vary and there's no guarantee there will be any at times.

Thanks

```
 'override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number,unscaledHeight:Number):void
    {
        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        var g:Graphics = graphics;
        g.clear();
        var grid1:DataGrid = DataGrid(DataGridListData(listData).owner);
        //var rowtotal:int = new int(dp[0].length) ;
        if (grid1.isItemSelected(data) || grid1.isItemHighlighted(data))
            return;
        if (data[DataGridListData(listData).dataField]== "NJ")
        {
             g.beginFill(0xCC0033);
             g.drawRect(0, 0, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
             g.endFill();
        }
    }'
```

Comment: if it is spark datagrid you can do this by skinning.

Comment: I added the code above which I am now using to fill the background but it only fills the cell. is there something I am missing to fill the full row that contains the cell.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6015763/842112 refer this It will work

Comment: that is just to change the font colour which can be done in the as file anyway. Difficulty is changing the background color of the row.

Comment: did you tried that? don't just read try it .., 
`You can override your DataGrid's drawRowBackground method, and check whether it needs custom background or not. `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a Itemrenderer for achieving this. In the itemrenderer setdata method you can write the condition for the column for changing the background color of the row to the desired color.